# Convergence of a series involving cotangent function

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Is the following series convergent or not and why? $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \cot(\pi/2 - 1/n)$.

I don't know why I cannot get this, but I was expecting either $\cot(\pi/2 - 1/n) < x^{2}$ or $\cot(\pi/2 - 1/n) > x$ near $x = 0$. I cannot show neither of them at this moment; hence the question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have

$$\cot\left(\frac\pi2-\frac1n\right)=\tan\left(\frac1n\right)\sim_\infty\frac1n$$
so the given series is divergent by comparison with the harmonic series $\sum_n\frac1n$.